# how to make a function that looks thru first argument and returns an array that is equal to the second argument

Tags: javascript

I'm making a function that looks thru an array of the first argument and returns an array with all the objects that are matching the second argument. i dont know what is wrong with my code or how to fix it. i would appreciated it if you can help me

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  const arr = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  for (let i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(collection[i])) {
      arr.push(collection[i])
    }

  }

  // Only change code above this line
  return arr;
}

whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

Comment: Do you only have to match one (the `last`) field?

Comment: no, the last field indicates which object from the first argument you have to return. e.g. if second argument is asking for last: "Capulet", my function should return {first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want to match the `last` field in a object.

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  return collection.filter(({ last }) => last === source.last);
}

const result = whatIsInAName(
  [
    { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" },
    { first: "Mercutio", last: null },
    { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" },
  ],
  { last: "Capulet" }
);

console.log(result);
```

Here we're just using a [Filter Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the collection array. The function predicate (`({ last }) => last === source.last`) we're passing in the filter will receive each object from the collection and check if `source.last === received.last`.

The is the same as the following one:

```js
function doesMatch(receivedObject) {
    if(receivedObject.last === source.last) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why `source.hasOwnProperty` isn't working as expected:

If you run `console.log` you will see that you are looping through the **elements** in `collection` which are `objects`.

**Example:**

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  const arr = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  for (let i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
    console.log(collection[i]);
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(collection[i])) {
      arr.push(collection[i])
    }

  }

  // Only change code above this line
  return arr;
}

whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

But what you *actually* want to do (if you're checking properties, aka *keys*) is loop through the `keys` in each `object`.

For that, you need a second loop inside the first.

- the first loop will cycle through the `object elements`
- the second loop will cycle through the `keys` in each `object element`

Usefully, you can use:

```
Object.keys()
```

to return an array of `object keys` (for each object) to loop through.

So your second loop can be another `for loop`.

**Example:**

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  const arr = [];
  
  // Only change code below this line
  for (let i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
  
    // Object Keys to Loop Through
    let myKeys = Object.keys(collection[i]);

    // Object Values
    let myValues = Object.values(collection[i]);
    
    for (let j = 0; j < myKeys.length; j++) {
      
      if ((source.hasOwnProperty(myKeys[j])) && (source[myKeys[j]] === myValues[j])) {
        arr.push(collection[i])
      }
    }
  }
  
  console.log(arr);

  // Only change code above this line
  return arr;
}

whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but i think maybe i havent describes the problem properly. i am making a function that looks through an array of objects (first argument) and returns an array of all objects that have matching name and value pairs (second argument). Each name and value pair of the source object has to be present in the object from the collection if it is to be included in the returned array

Comment: For this `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` and `===` are all the tools you need on top of what you have put together already. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is the mistake:

```
if (source.hasOwnProperty(collection[i])) {
//                        ^ collection[i] is an object, not a property
```

It may be an idea to use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here. Something like:

```js
const whatIsInAName = (collection, source) => {
  // compare for all keys keys in [source]
  const compare = (obj1, obj2, keys) => 
    keys.filter( k => obj1[k] === obj2[k] ).length > 0;
  // filter using comparison method
  return collection.filter( r => compare(source, r, Object.keys(source)) );
};
const collection2CompareTo = [
  { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, 
  { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, 
  { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }];
// expect: [{ first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], 
const c1 = whatIsInAName(collection2CompareTo, { last: "Capulet" });
// expect: [{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }]
const c2 = whatIsInAName(collection2CompareTo, { first: "Romeo" });
// expect: [{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }]
const c3 = whatIsInAName(collection2CompareTo, { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" });
// expect: []
const c4 = whatIsInAName(collection2CompareTo, { first: undefined, last: "Void" });

document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = `c1: ${
  JSON.stringify(c1, null, 2)}\nc2: ${
  JSON.stringify(c2, null, 2)}\nc3: ${
  JSON.stringify(c3, null, 2)}\nc4: ${
  JSON.stringify(c4, null, 2)}`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    first: 'Romeo',
    last: 'Montague',
  },
  {
    first: 'Mercutio',
    last: null,
  },
  {
    first: 'Tybalt',
    last: 'Capulet',
  },
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    first: 'Romeo',
    last: 'Montague',
  },
  {
    first: 'Tybalt',
    last: '',
  },
];

const findMatches = (array1, array2) =>
  array1.filter((item1) =>
    array2.find((item2) => JSON.stringify(item1) === JSON.stringify(item2))
  );

const result = findMatches(arr1, arr2);

console.log(result);
```